# Importing date from csv in R

Tags: r, csv, date

I want to import a excel file into r and the file contains a column with date and time in this form:

```
20.08.2018  16:32:20
```

If I change to standard format in the csv file itself it looks like this:

```
43332,68912
```

If I read in the file by using `read_excel()` R this date looks like this:

```
43332.689120370371
```

How can I turn the current format into a date format in R?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes, that would save the long conversation we are having below my answer, trying to figure out what your data looks like :)

Answer (score 4):

It is a good practice not to edit anything in a `.csv` (or excel) file—so to treat them as read only—and to make changes in a script (so in R).

Let's call your data frame "my_df" and your datetime variable "date".

```
library(readr)
library(magrittr)

my_df$date %<>% parse_datetime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

---

**Edit:** Trying to piece together information from your comments, I created an excel file with one column called `STARTED` with date and time in the form `20.08.2018 16:32:20` as you indicate in the question. Since you seem to like `readxl`:

```
library(readxl)
library(magrittr)

myData <- read_excel("myData.xlsx")

myData$STARTED %<>% parse_datetime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Which is the same code I already wrote above. This gives:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  STARTED            
  <dttm>             
1 2018-08-20 16:32:20
```

If you only get `NA`, your data is not in the format given by your example `20.08.2018 16:32:20`.

Comment: Thanks! When I apply your code:

myData$STARTED <- readr::parse_datetime(myData$STARTED, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S") it unfortunately turns out as NAs :(

Comment: Can you share a little bit more of your .csv file?

Comment: STARTED
Zeitpunkt zu dem das Interview begonnen hat
20.8.18 16:32
20.8.18 16:34
20.8.18 17:03
20.8.18 17:09
20.8.18 17:58

Comment: But once you import your .csv in R (in a data frame I imagine), what does your datetime column look like?

Comment: this is how the column looks: first row= STARTED, second row = Zeitpunkt...., third row = 20.08.18 16:32

Comment: like "43332.689120370371" for one date

Comment: Oh, that's not what you wrote in your question. Is it "20.08.2018 16:32:20" or "20.08.18 16:32"?

Comment: this looks the same as the standard format of the date in excel

Comment: In the later case, replace `parse_datetime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")` with `parse_datetime("%d.%m.%y %H:%M")`

Comment: well, because I chose a format for the columns where the seconds aren't  shown. but the actual information (in the line in excel where your  complete input stands) the seconds are included...I hope you understand?

Comment: What I want to know is what you get in R.

Comment: First, import your `.csv` file in R (with `read_csv()` for instance), then let me know what format you have for your date and time variable.

Comment: sorry, I am a very beginner with programmin...did't I tell you already? 43332.689120370371 is the format in r after I imported the data. So for each date a long digit like the upper one appears

Comment: Ok. I thought that this was what you were getting after you had made some changes directly in your `.csv` file.

Comment: See my edits. Don't do anything in your .csv file nor in excel. If your data looks like  "20.08.2018 16:32:20" in your excel file, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Following your discussion with @prosoitos, it looks like the import function cannot make sense of your date column:

Your line of example data in the comments contains no quotes around your date string. That implies that you copied that data either by opening it with excel (or similar) or your survey tool does not qualify dates as strings. Did you open our .csv in excel, saved it as .xlsx and tried to import the result in R? That would explain the mess you get, as excel could try to interpret the date strings and convert them to some funny Microsoft format nobody else uses.

Please don't do that, use a raw csv-file that was never touched with excel and import it directly into R.

Your read function obviously does not understand the content of your date variable and apparently replaces it with some [unix standard time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), which are seconds since 1970. However, it looks like those time stamps are invalid (43332 is something like noon on 1970/01/01), else you could easily transform them to human readable dates.

I suggest you try importing your csv with:

```
read.csv("your_data.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

You may have to specify your seperator, e.g. `sep = "\t"` (for a tab-seperated file), if it is not *whitespace*, which is the default seperatpr of the read function. After that, the dates in your dataframe are simple text strings and you can follow up with what @prosoitos said.

(Sorry for adding an additional answer. I would have commented to @prosoitos answer, but I have insufficent reputation points.)

Answer (score -1):

Read CSV into R MyData

```
read.csv(file="TheDataIWantToReadIn.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
```

Comment: sorry, I gave some wrong information in my question and edited it now. I read in an excel file by using read_excel. If I do so it returns the weird date format...